# Featured image appears in header

Tags: images

I'm using a featured image so that my post gets that image when it is posted to social media. The problem is that the a slice of the image appears in the header of the post, like this (featured image slice is in the red rectangle):
[image]

I have read some advice saying that I should not place both have the image as featured and put it into the post itself. However, removing the image from the post only does just that - removing it from the post but keeping it in the header, which is the reverse of what I want.

So how do I get rid of it from the header?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the post that has problem.

Comment: It's here: http://blog.qoorp.se/?p=1179&preview=1&_ppp=3fdced0f8f

Comment: You should look in your header code for logic at `<div id="header-image-main-inside">`. You will know why the problem occur. I can't say anything because I don't know the logic for display header image.

Comment: But where do I see the header code? This is produced inside Wordpress, and only know how to access the text itself, not the header code. I suspect there is a simpler solution, since all the other posts I have made in my blog, for example http://wp.me/p7IwbX-io, does not have this problem. I just don't know why the featured image appears in this weird way for this one.